# Calculating the ceiling in MASM project

Tags: assembly, masm, ceil

So I want to calculate the ceiling of something like `x/2` in case `x` is an odd number or something.  I'm not sure how to do this in assembly language and I can't find anything good online.  Not even sure this is possible but I'm sure there's some way to get it done.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for unsigned numbers:

```
shr eax, 1
adc eax, 0
```